# Undefined symbols on defined constructor and function, why?

Tags: c++, class

I have a physics Vector class which requires a constructor and to string function. When I compile the class I get the following error:

I invoke the compiler like so: `g++ main.cpp -o main`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Vector::toString()", referenced from:
      _main in main-3acaf8.o
  "Vector::Vector()", referenced from:
      _main in main-3acaf8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Which implies I have not defined the constructor and toString function. Here is my code, how do I resolve this?

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Vector {

    const static int d = 3, xPos = 0, yPos = 1, zPos = 2;
    double components[d];

    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(double x, double y, double z);
        Vector(const Vector &v1);
        void setVector(double x, double y, double z);
        double getX();
        double getY();
        double getZ();
        double magnitude();
        Vector getUnitVector();
        double dot(Vector v1, Vector v2);
        void scale(double c);
        Vector add(Vector v1, Vector v2);
        Vector subtract(Vector v1, Vector v2);
        Vector crossProduct(Vector v1, Vector v2);
        void toString();
};
```

cpp file:

```
#include "vector.hpp"

Vector::Vector(){
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        components[i] = 0;

... // all other functions

void Vector::toString(){
    printf("x: %lf, y: %lf, z: %lf\n", 
        components[0], components[1], components[2]);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Compiler and linker command line please! We can't tell from what you posted.

Comment: Isn't that what I put at the top of my post?

Comment: No, you just show the error messages, not how you invoked the compiler.

Comment: I added the g++ main.cpp -o main

Comment: Thus you obviously should have `g++ Vector.cpp main.cpp -o main`.

Comment: Yeh but main uses the vector class

Comment: g++ vector.cpp -o vector
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Read my comment thoroughly again please. And please also read the dupe target to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works but why do I need to add vector.cpp and main.cpp when invoking the compiler

Comment: How else should the compiler know from where to take the implementation of your class?